# How to find parent of selected element routerLinkActive?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

There is a link:

```
<li>
 <ul>
    <a [routerLink]="menu.getRouteUrl(item)" routerLinkActive="active">Link</a>
 </ul>
</li>
```

How to set class for parent `li` when `routerLinkActive="active"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move `routerLinkActive` to parent element.

```html
<li routerLinkActive="active">
  <a [routerLink]="menu.getRouteUrl(item)">Link</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `isActive` property of [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#properties) directive, as follows;

```html
<li [ngClass]="{'classNameWhenLinkActive': myLink.isActive}">
 <ul>
    <a #myLink="routerLinkActive" [routerLink]="menu.getRouteUrl(item)" routerLinkActive="active">Link</a>
 </ul>
</li>
```

here is a simple demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upqogp